# Объясните в чем причина deadlock-а?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Нашел на хабре пример deadlock-а:

```
template <typename T>
class container 
{
     std::mutex _lock;
     std::vector<T> _elements;
public:
     void add(T element) 
     {
          _lock.lock();
          _elements.push_back(element);
          _lock.unlock();
     } 
 void addrange(int num, ...)
 {
      va_list arguments;
      va_start(arguments, num);
      for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
      {
           _lock.lock();
           add(va_arg(arguments, T));
           _lock.unlock();
      }
      va_end(arguments); 
 }
 void dump()
 {
      _lock.lock();
      for(auto e: _elements)
      std::cout << e << std::endl;
      _lock.unlock();
 }
};

void threadFunction(container<int> &c)
{
     c.addrange(3, rand(), rand(), rand());
}

int main()
{
 srand((unsigned int)time(0));
 container<int> cntr;
 std::thread t1(threadFunction, std::ref(cntr));
 std::thread t2(threadFunction, std::ref(cntr));
 std::thread t3(threadFunction, std::ref(cntr));
 t1.join();
 t2.join();
 t3.join();
 cntr.dump();
 return 0;
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что дедлок возникает из-за того что в одном и том же потоке вызывается `addrange` в котором сначала идет `_lock.lock()` а затем `add` в которой опять идет `_lock.lock()`? если да, то почему в следующем примере нету дедлока(слегка измененный в худшую сторону пример из книги Энтони Уильямса, где я специально `unlock()` не сделал):

```
struct Y {
private:
mutable std::mutex m;
int data;
int get_data() const {
    m.lock();
    return data;
}

public:
Y(int&& data_) : data(std::move(data_)) {}
friend bool operator==(Y const& lhs, Y const& rhs) {
    if(&lhs==&rhs)
        return true;
    auto lhs_ = lhs.get_data();
    auto rhs_ = rhs.get_data();
    return (lhs_==rhs_);
}
};

int main() {
    Y y1(1); Y y2(2);
    std::cout<<(y1==y2)<<std::endl;
}
```

Тут тоже идет два раза подряд вызов `get_data()` где делается `lock()` без `unlock()`, однако программа не виснет, как в первом случае а все отрабатывает на ура

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По стандарту поведение для повторного вызова [std::mutex::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) в одном потоке для одного и того же [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) не определено:

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the
>   behavior is undefined: for example, the program may deadlock.

В том числе, может возникнуть deadlock. В конкретной реализации, например в VS2015, в этом случае возникает исключение.

Ваш второй пример вызывает метод std::mutex::lock у *разных* объектов std::mutex, поэтому описанный выше эффект не возникает.

Comment: эмм... как у разных? поля ж класса то одно...
ах да... я чет и не заметил... часа три уже ответа ждал на простой вопрос получается)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там нет разблокировки.

Comment: @ixSci да, точно. Но в таком случае, код - бред. Оператор сравнения можно вызвать только 1 раз :)

Comment: Свои пять копеек, почему в данном случае стандарт оговаривает неопределённое поведение: есть системы где мутексы всегда рекурсивные, т.е. они могут нормально блочиться сколько угодно раз одним потоком, главное что бы столько же фактов снятия блокировки было. Пример - RTOS ThreadX. Если бы реализация мутекса была сделана поверх этого API и было бы оговорено: дедлочится! Пришлось бы городить дополнительные костыли. На Linux используется POSIX Threads, там тоже оговаривается неопределённое поведение в таком случае: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html